# Increasing Screen Resolution in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, screen

I've noticed that the standard screen dimensions for a java window (using Panel or JFrame) are in the range of about 1200x800 (so about a million pixels). The laptop I'm using has about 4 million pixels (about 2500x1600).

A. Why does java condense and pixelate the screen like this? Is it just JFrame/JPanel?

B. How do I get a window with a resolution that automatically matches the screen's maximum resolution (preferably still in swing)?

Comment: Can you provide some code (and perhaps an image) that demonstrates what you’re talking about?  Java doesn’t have a “standard dimension” for a window;  the size is either what you set it to, or the result of calling `pack()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive the size of the monitor you'll use this code:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = screenSize.getWidth();
int height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

To set the size of a frame you'll use this code:

```
jframe.setSize(witdh, height);
```

Comment: Running that, I get the dimensions to be 1440x900, which are much less than what they should be at. It seems to still be using the standard pixel spacing amount, which is what I'm wanting to fix.